# Change CSS style of tr based on Markdown bold emphasis

Tags: css, markdown

I'm currently writing my first blog in markdown and trying to style a table in CSS.
The table in my markdown file is:

```
| | Experiment 1 | Experiment 2 |
|-| ------- | ------- |
|**Ingredients**|**696g**|**696g**|
|White Flour|274g|274g|
|Brown Flour|134g|134g|
|Water|250g|300g|
|Sugar|13g|13g|
|Olive Oil|17g|17g|
|Salt|8g|8g|
|**Flour Type Distribution**|**408g**|**408g**|
|White Flour|67%|67%|
|Brown Flour|33%|33%|
|**Hydration Rate**|**61%**|**73%**|
|**Oven Specs**|||
```

Which is formatted using [this](https://github.com/jpescador/hugo-future-imperfect/blob/master/static/css/main.css) css file, to output [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heuB6.png).
But, what I actually want to do is to only change the `background-color` CSS property of the rows where the `td` is set to bold in markdown (surrounded by **).

For example, in the above table, the rows that I want to change the `background-color` of are:

- `|**Ingredients**|**696g**|**696g**|`
- `|**Flour Type Distribution**|**408g**|**408g**|`
- `|**Hydration Rate**|**61%**|**73%**|`
- `|**Oven Specs**|||`

Is that possible? Or is there any other workaround that I can use to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

if it was an attribute you could select their content and edit on css(say it was a value instead of an innerHTML content):

```
td[value^="**"]{background-color: red}
```

> "^"shows that the value should START with this

Documentation Link: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp

according to my knowledge there is no CSS only solution. you can try using javascript. let me know if you want to implement it on Javascript. I'll Help.